# MySQLi update not working, mutilple colums and two where clauses

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have been debugging this for over 30 minutes and I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I just started using MySQLi and thats one of the things that I keep messing up. I think it might have something to do with preg_replace I have only used this once before so i still am not very good with it.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start(); 

include("../include/config.php");
include("../include/functions.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['pv1_session']) && $_SESSION['pv1_session'] == true) {

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $uid = idinfo($_SESSION['pv1_user_id'],"idu");
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $_POST['fid']);

    $post_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $_POST['name']);
    $post_tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $_POST['tags']);

    $name = preg_replace("/[^\w a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9._-]/u", "_", $post_name);
    $tags = preg_replace("/[^\w a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9._-]/u", "_", $post_tags);
    $file = preg_replace("/[^\wa-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9._-]/u", "_", $post_name);

    $update = mysqli_query($mysql,"UPDATE files SET name='$name', filename='$file', tags='$tags' WHERE user_id='$uid' AND filehash='$id'");

if (!$update) { 
    echo "<p>Unable to update file.</p>";
    exit;
} else {
echo "<p>Success: Your uploaded file has been updated!</p>";
$pro_url = $web['url'].'/account/manage_uploads.php';
header("Location: $pro_url");
}

}

} else {
  echo "ERROR: Please log in first!";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can you share any error messages or unexpected behaviour you're experiencing?

Comment: Add ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your php script. Or edit php.ini to enable these by default.And using exit; after header redirection is a good habit. It's not essential for your example, but you should know that script don't stop with executing after header() call.

Comment: Ahh thats it I had `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` not `error_reporting(E_ALL);` now I'm seeing the errors it's to do with the `$fid` on line 13 Undefined index

Comment: There you go :) Now check your html form, and check if all values are sent. Use isset() function. If you want to see what is sent from your form, use var_dump($_POST) or var_dump($_GET) accordingly.

Comment: I left out name="fid" in the form <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

Answer (score 0):

Use "prepared statements" (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

This gives you two advantages:

- it handles the escaping for you (and also does it right: you do the escaping BEFORE the preg_replace, and that could go very wrong)
- it also provides you with very easy debug. You put the parameters into an array, and you can simple echo out (`print_r`) the parameters array and see what your preg_replace has done.

Comment: I tried the prepared statements and I still can't get them to work

Comment: Did you echo (print_r) the parameters to screen? Did "id" and "fid" appear correctly (as you need in the database)?